# How to set non-blinking text cursor (assembly)?

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

My program should set non-blinking text cursor. I only have found how to hide cursor (using 10h). 
Cursor should be visible but non-blinking. Is it possible?

Comment: Not by VGA hardware. You have to hide the cursor and draw the inverse character yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The VGA uses bit 7 of the attribute byte to indicate blinking.  You can turn off this feature so that you can use bit 7 to indicate intensity.

An old note I have is now only [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150711183600/scatcat.fhsu.edu/~jplang2/asm-blink.html)'ed, but I have been using some code that has worked for some time.

```
       ; =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
       ; make sure the 'blink' bit is off
       ; this is so we can print bright colors instead of the
       ;  vga using bit 7 as the blink bit.
       mov  dx,3DAh             ; reset the flip-flop
       in   al,dx

       mov  dx,3C0h             ; index 0x10  (20h + 10h)?
       mov  al,30h
       out  dx,al

       inc  dx                  ;  clear bit 3 to disable blink
       in   al,dx
       and  al,(~(1<<3))
       dec  dx
       out  dx,al
```

Please note that this assumes there is a standard VGA, these particular registers are at 0x3DA, 0x3C0, and 0x3C1, this will be run from TRUE DOS--not a Windowed Session, along with a lot of other assumptions.

Again, this must be on a TRUE DOS machine, or at least a platform that actually is using the VGA hardware instead of emulating it.  Also, don't be surprised if modern hardware doesn't even have the VGA hardware anymore.

With all of these assumptions, as Jester stated, it would be best to hide the cursor and draw your own.

However, if you do get this to work, and it should in a standard older style machines, it allows you to use the intensity colors, i.e.: bright white, bright blue, etc.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_Mode_Cursor doesn't mention being able to disable cursor blinking.  http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/attrreg.htm does, though (linked from osdev's [VGA links page](https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Resources).

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't this giving you blinking *text* characters, not controlling cursor blinking?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I read blink and instantly went toward some old notes I had on blinking characters instead of blinking cursor.  My mistake.